# Updating tkinter label text

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a little script that takes some values from a web page and displays them as tkinter labels. The values are updated every 5 minutes. How can I make the labels update every time the values change?

```
url = 'https://myurl.something'
def check():
    sleep(300)
    value1 = str(requests.get(url))

root = Tk()
label1 = label(root, text=value1)
label1.grid()

while True:
    check()
root.mainloop()
```

I know that the sleep loop could never work, but that's how I did this before adding a GUI

Comment: add your code please

Comment: Here's some [docmentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) that describes the universal `after()` method. Note you shouldn't call `time.sleep()` in a tkinter program, it will make it hang—but `after()` won't. Lastly, your `while True:` loop will prevent the `root.mainloop()` from ever being executed since it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some basic code to get you started. I took out the requests stuff, as it is not really relevant to your problem.

The key things are

- The `StringVar`, which allows you to update your text.
- The use of `after`, to shift your periodic task away from the gui
  thread. No need for `sleep`.

code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar

def check(val):
    # do your request.get here
    sv.set("dummy text %d" % val)
    root.after(1000, lambda: check(val + 1))

root = Tk()

sv = StringVar()
sv.set("waiting...")
label1 = Label(root, textvariable=sv)
label1.grid()

root.after(1000, lambda: check(1))
root.mainloop()
```

Given this code, hopefully you can fit your http request back in and it will do what you want.